# Upload working local client but not on web server

Tags: c#, asp.net, youtube-api

I am using the YouTube API to upload videos from my ASP.net web application to YouTube.
I have used this example:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/dotnet#upload_a_video

I have got this working on my Loacl PC where I can upload a video.  To get this working I obtained a "**Client ID for native application**" from the Google Developer Console and downloaded the required json.

However I have now uploaded my website to a live server and wish to get it working.

I have now generated a "**Client ID for *web* application**" and replaced the json file that I was using.

Is this all I have to do?? Because I have tried this and my file is not appearing on YouTube.

Here are the IDs that I have generated. 
I have simply used the web application JSON instead of the native one.
[image]

Comment: dont you need to whitelist your ip or allow your domain to call the API?

Comment: What do you mean by this meda?  In the Google Console when I generate a client ID for my web application I set "Authorized JavaScript origins" to be www.mywebsite.com and "Authorized redirect URI" to be https://www.mywebsite.com/oauth2callback

Comment: I'm not sure about the https://www.mywebsite.com/oauth2callback and whats its about though.....

Comment: Do I need change any settings on my Hosting Webserver???

Comment: Look in your screen shot , you still have the localhost in the redirect URi

Comment: Yes but that is for the "Client ID for native application" which I used for my native project.  For my web project I'm using the bottom image JSON.

Comment: The Redirect URI for the bottom image states "/oauth2callback".  THis was the default uri that the google console gave me.  I do not have this on my website so can I remove this or do I need to add this to my website???